# Is it possible to define a structure contains arbitrary size array in GLSL 440

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to define structure in my shader, which contains an array of size 20. And I put the structure as follow:

```
struct BoneWeightL1{
    float bone_weights[20];
};

struct BoneIdL1{
    int bone_ids[20];
};
```

The shader compiler returns the following error on both line I define array:
error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting "::" at token "[".

It is illegible to put put array inside struct? Is there any other way to achieve this kind of data struct in GLSL 440?

Comment: Just to be sure it isn't just a typo, but you know `GLfloat` (and `GLuint`) is rubbish, do you?

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing it out, but the problem still remains after I make the  correction...

Comment: It is perfectly valid to put an array inside a struct in GLSL, the only restriction is that the size be a constant integral expression > 0. This behavior has existed since version 1.1 of GLSL, so your version number is extraneous information. Judging by the names of the fields in these structs, you might actually want to use a Uniform Buffer Object or Shader Storage Block instead of a couple of generic structs (the later of the two does not require a constant compile-time known size); look into [interface blocks](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)).